# How to embed my YouTube Channel videos to my Website without displaying on YouTube?

Tags: javascript, web-applications, youtube, youtube-api, embed

I am setting up my website and I want to embed my private YouTube channel videos on my Website. Is it possible to use the YouTube API to do this?

Comment: What have you investigated? Why do you think this is possible?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2UserAgent#validatetoken

Comment: hope above link gives you an idea what i m trying to do !

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the `YouTube` brand name on the video by using the `modestbranding` parameter on the embeded video. More parameters can be found at https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters. Below is a preview image. Please click on eithor the image or the link below it for the code and the live demo.



<== Because you are new, I will explain this checkmark. Clicking this checkmark chooses my answer as the best. You can change this again later. Please click this checkmark if you think my answer is better than all other answers posted here. Otherwise, please click someone else's checkmark at your convenience. Clicking the checkmark is purely voluntary. It is not required.

[image]

Please see https://jsfiddle.net/zew0rhpb/ for the demo.